# Mechanical Turk API: Why is HITReviewStatus always "NotReviewed"?

Tags: perl, api, mechanicalturk

Even after all the "Assigments" for a HIT have been manually reviewed and "accepted" via the Amazon Mturk UI, the HIT still shows a HITReviewStatus of "NotReviewed"?

Has any else noticed this?

When does the HITReviewStatus change for a given HIT?

I'm creating a set of automation scripts, so this status field is very important.

Thanks!

EDIT: The HITReviewStatus only shows up via the API when using the "GetHIT" operation

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer in an obscure amzn PDF:

"
If a HIT is submitted that violates Mechanical
Turk's policies for appropriate content, a
Mechanical Turk user can request that a HIT
be reviewed by an administrator. HITReviewStatus indicates whether the HIT has
not been reviewed, has been marked for review by a user, or has been reviewed by an
administrator and deemed appropriate or inappropriate.
"

SO it appears that HITReviewStatus is an internal auditing status for AMZN.